# Issue with types using quick sort algorithm

Tags: c++, templates, sorting, types

I am having an issue with different types in a implementation of the quick sort algorithm using iterator templates and I cannot figure out what's going on.

The algorithm is the following:

```
template <typename I> void ordenacion_rapida(I i, I j, int n0=1)
{
    int n = j-i;

    if (n<=n0)
        ordenacion_insercion<I>(i, j);
    else
    {
        I p = pivote(i, j);
        ordenacion_rapida<I>(i, p);
        ordenacion_rapida<I>(p+1, j);
    }
}

template <typename I> I pivote(I i, I j)
{
    I p = i;
    typedef typename iterator_traits<I>::value_type tipo;
    tipo x = *(i);

    for (I k=i+1; k<j; ++k)
        if (*(k)<=x)
        {
            ++p;
            tipo aux = *(p);
            *(p) = *(k);
            *(k) = aux;
        }
    *(i) = *(p);
    *(p) = x;
}

template <typename I> void ordenacion_insercion(I i, I j)
{
    typedef typename iterator_traits<I>::value_type tipo;
    for (I k=i+1; k<j; ++k)
    {
        tipo x = *(k);
        while (k!=i && x<*(k-1))
        {
            *(k) = *(k-1);
            --k;
        }
        *(k) = x;
    }
}
```

Forgive me if there is an exccessive quantity of code but the problem might be in any line, which I have exhaustively analyzed.

The thing is that when I try to sort a `vector<double` or `vector<float>` I am reported an error whereas there is no such problem when I use `vector<int>`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: what error are you reported?

Comment: Is there anything your algorithm does that `std::sort` does not do just as well or better?

Comment: You don't return anything from `pivote`.

Comment: indeed I don't return anything from pivote, I am stupid. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to see anything wrong with your code, it works perfectly fine. The only issue is you forgot to return something inside `pivote`.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename I> void ordenacion_insercion(I i, I j)
{
    // snip
}

template <typename I> I pivote(I i, I j)
{
    // snip

    // Assuming you intended to return P
    return p;
}

template <typename I> void ordenacion_rapida(I i, I j, int n0=1)
{
    // snip
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v = { 1.2f, 0.5f, 3.5f, 0.2f };
    ordenacion_rapida(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
} // 0.2 0.5 1.2 3.5
```